# What happens if you put a capacitor in the wrong direction for a short time?

Tags: capacitor

I have a 6300uF capacitor rated for 50V. When I connected it to my circuit I put it in the wrong way. After a few seconds I realized my mistake and switch off the circuit. I want to know if any damage have been done to the capacitor. It is not bulging and it did not explode. 
Edit it is applied to a 13v 10 amp max supply. It is a aluminum  Electrolytic capacitor Panasonic. 
Datasheet:http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ABA0000/ABA0000C121.pdf

Comment: bang, brz, zslslslzzzzz

Comment: @PlasmaHH, in few seconds only...??? Will it not take more than that (assuming few seconds ~ 1-2 sec)

Comment: @abhishektyagi: We have no idea how exactly it was connected and how much voltage and current it got, but in a given situation like yours, there were a lot of caps that have been damaged or even exploded. A lot of damage can not be seen, but only measured e.g. by reduced capacitance, increased leakage, increased ESR etc.

Comment: Ya ...the exploding one ...I agree with that...saw it in one of the MIT lectures, using a electrolytic capacitor

Comment: I'm thinking about testing it by measuring its leakage current and healing the oxide dielectric, if need be.   How about posting the data sheet or a link to it, please?

Comment: http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ABA0000/ABA0000C121.pdf

Comment: Discontinued as Panasonic no longer makes snap in caps.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't say what technology the capacitor is, but considering it's 6.3 mF, 50 V, and polarized, I'll assume it's a aluminum electrolytic.

Yes, the capacitor has gotten damaged, at least somewhat.  How badly damaged, and how irreversible the damage depends on what voltage was applied for how long.  A 50 V capacitor can probably take 5 V in reverse for a few seconds, and probably mostly recover when promptly forward biased.

The prognosis gets worse at higher voltage and longer time.  The insulating layer formed on the surface of the aluminum gets eaten away, so eventually there is a short.  You have already damaged the insulating layer somewhat.  It can actually heal somewhat when forward voltage is applied, so it's hard to say how bad the damage is.

If this is a commercial application, toss the capacitor, replace it with a new one, and don't look back.  If this is a hobby application where you can tolerate the capacitor blowing up or leaking in the future, then continue on and be more careful next time.

To paraphrase Dirty Harry: *"Do you feel lucky?  Well do you, punk?"*

Comment: I agree, as a cheapskate hobbyist, continue using it, but mark it with something and when you're done, put it in the box of components labeled "Hmm..."

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use it even in a hobby application. I had a near miss accident with a smaller cap blowing up on the table, perhaps some ten inches from where my head was. The case of the capacitor flew off and got stuck in a plastic ceiling panel.

That cap you may have damaged is nearly not as expensive as to justify the risk.

Comment: The design of capacitors seems to have changed at some point. Old capacitors would blow their entire case off, modern ones just seem to rupture.

Comment: Must've been k50-6...

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a protected environment (Your application has some kind of protective case) I'd definitely use it.

Otherwise, I wouldn't. I know it's a thrilling experience being beside a cap that can blow up in any moment, but it won't be that fun if it ends up in your eye socket :P.